# How can I inject raw packets onto my network

Tags: networking, device-driver, ethernet

In testing certain network device driver receive features, I need to send special packets on the wire.  I know I need to open a raw socket and push the bytes out.  Is there some well-known example (C, perl, whatever) code already available for playing at this level?

(added later) I would prefer non-platform-specific answers, they'll be the most useful for everyone.

Comment: It should be mentioned that there are no raw sockets in Windows XP SP2 and later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there's a good C example here at [Security-Freak](http://www.security-freak.net/packet-injection/packet-injection.html), which only needed a little modification for flexibility.  I'm hoping there are more answers in other languages.

Comment: It may be poor form so select one's own answer, but this is what I was looking for and found for myself: simple, quick and dirty code that already existed.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the documentation for [packet](http://linux.die.net/man/7/packet). Basically, you create a socket with SOCK_RAW or SOCK_DGRAM, then write to the socket using normal socket i/o. However, the data you send will be put directly on the line, rather than automatically getting the headers that are necessary for most network interop.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sendrawpacket.aspx

There's already an existing project that may be able to help you with this.

Comment: Hmmm - this looks like a platform specific answer (aspx) and I have to set up some account to get access?  Bah.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/wiki/tcprewrite#RewritingLayer2
and http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you are looking for a tool to generate your own packets, Scapy is such a tool often used in the security industry (such as pentesters).

Demo is available: http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any examples.  But you should just be able to open up a UDP socket to any IP address you like and start writing data to it.  Make sure its UDP or this will not work.